# Converting a PDF for use with DVD Studio Pro

Tags: software, pdf

I have a client who want me to add PDF's to a DVD, so that people can view them through their televisions

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is dated link, but for what is worth...

DVD Studio Pro allows you to create a Data DVD alongside the video DVD.

Check your DVDSP Inspector for DVD Assets. This is a great way to include files and images, even presentations that you wish clients to open and view.

There is also DVD@ccess which allows you to embed URLs into buttons that will cause the DVD player to stop (on a computer) and launch your browser.

Just FYI

Comment: this is what we did in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. You need to convert the pages of the PDF into images and handle accordingly from there, much like a photo slide show. The primary concern I would have is whether the PDF is laid out so that it looks good on screen.

Acrobat (the full version, not Reader) can export all pages to a variety of formats. Acrobat costs good money, but Preview only exports the first page. Ghostscript via Terminal might have a free alternative, but the interface is the command line.

Comment: My first try would be a simple drag-and-drop from Preview to DVD Studio Pro.

Comment: @mouviciel nice try, but the blessing hasn’t arrived there yet, and DVD is “so abandoned” by Apple that we might never see anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [PDF to Keynote](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/freesoftware/pdftokeynote.html), and then just export from Keynote as a QuickTime movie.